# VPN to tunnel thru home IP address

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, remote-access

Working remotely, I have a lot of things that require my home IP address to be able to login and do work.

If I were to use my laptop in say a place like a cafe which would obviously have a different IP, is it possible to connect to a VPN (or something) on my home computer that would allow me to connect to say a remote desktop which requires my home IP address, and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Here are a few options, https://www.howtogeek.com/221001/how-to-set-up-your-own-home-vpn-server/